# ${\bf F}=m{\bf a}$ versus ${\bf F}=\frac{\mathrm d{\bf p}}{\mathrm dt}$ alternate expressions (differential)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, momentum, acceleration

I am currently collecting research about theories to do with accelerated motion, and scientists who were involved in the development of such theories.

Intrinsically, [Newton's Second Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) came up. While this has most of time appeared in the form of $F=ma$, Wikipedia gave two forms, first in terms of differential terms: 
$$F=\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dt}\text{ and then }F=m\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt.}$$

I was wondering if these different forms change the meaning of the equation somehow, as I have read that the differential form is "more accurate". However, mathematically, $\mathrm dv/\mathrm dt$ is the same as acceleration and hence $F=m\,\mathrm dv/\mathrm dt$ should be the same as $F=ma$ (I think).

Could someone explain if these different forms actually make a difference?

Comment: note that momentum $p=mv$ so the second differential form assumes the mass of the body is constant for it to be equivalent to the first differential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in your question, they are exactly the same: take into account that $p = m·v$, and therefore, $$F = \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{d(m·v)}{dt} = m· \frac{dv}{dt} = m·a$$
, as m should be independent of $t$ to use the second Newton law.

There is no difference between the different forms you show in the question, but the differential forms are always more accurate than those that are not so: if you want to compute the acceleration of a car, you could either compute its velocity at instants 0s and 10s or do the same between 0 and 1s. The first number would be more like an average for those first ten seconds and the second an average for the first second. Therefore, if you want to know the acceleration of the car at the instant 0s, probably the second approach is far better than the first. The differential form assumes that the $\Delta t $ is practically 0, so the answer is going to be the best.

Comment: So the less time taken into consideration when computing acceleration, the "better"?

Comment: If what you want to compute is the acceleration at a certain instant of time, the less time, the better. As I say, if you want to know what is the acceleartion at instant t=0, if you take data from t=-10 and t=10, the result is going to be less accurate than if you use t=-0.00001 and t=0.0001 x)

Comment: I am aware that this might be branching on to a deeper topic (sorry), but how is less time better? Coming from a chemistry background, taking more time to sample generally means more accurate results.

Comment: Obviously, it depends on what you need to calculate the acceleration for but normally, when you compute accelerations, you want the result to be local. Therefore, if you use the data from t=-10 and t=10, what you will know is what has been the average acceleration during that period of time and not the actual acceleration at t=0...

Comment: I suppose in Chemistry taking more time to make an average avoid local results, that could become outliers. That same thing occurs when you want to show the speed of a car (you are not going to compute it for really small $\Delta t$ as the user would have a result changing "too much" or "for everthing" and it would be, therefore, useless). What you give is an average, for little $\Delta t$ but not practically zero.

Comment: Is that what you where asking for or am I getting lost? xD By the way, $p=m·v$ but $m$ is independent of $t$, so both forms are giving you exactly the same information.

Comment: No, sorry I just phrased my comment poorly, and got confused as a result. I was just asking whether the different forms of the equation made a difference :)

Comment: Both forms are exactly the same. $p=m·v$ but when you compute its derivative it gives the same result, because m is independent of time (I suppose that the mass of the object is constant. If it were not, you could not apply the 2nd Newton Law, as to use it the mass of the object must be constant).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63209/discussion-between-ccorbella-and-wangi-papa).

Answer (score 3):

[Newton's second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Newton.27s_second_law) is only valid for constant-mass systems, so
$$
{\bf F}=\frac{\rm d {\bf p}}{{\rm d}t}\equiv\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\left(m{\bf v}\right)\equiv m\frac{\rm d {\bf v}}{{\rm d}t}\equiv m{\bf a}
$$ 
That is, they are all equivalent definitions for Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: So there is no advantage in using one form over another?

Comment: @WangiPaPa I guess it can be advantageous if the word problem uses mass & velocity instead of acceleration.

Comment: Why in most textbooks is stated that the correct form is:$$F=\frac{dp}{dt}$$

Answer (score 1):

Newton's law is $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$. This is more complete than $$F=ma$$ or the equivalent: $$F=m\frac{dv}{dt}$$ because it allows $m$ to vary with time, not just $v$. $F=ma$ is an approximation that assumes $m$ is constant. To see this, consider: $$F=\frac{dp}{dt}=\frac{d(mv)}{dt}=v\frac{dm}{dt}+\frac{m·dv}{dt}$$
where we have used $p=mv$. We can see that if we assume that the $dm/dt$ on the RHS is $0$, then we have $$\frac{dp}{dt}=m\frac{dv}{dt}$$

To answer your question about formatting: to get displayed equations, put them in double $ signs. I find [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) reference helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the solution to the formatting and your answer.
So because dp takes into account both "m" and "v" and thus allows both to change, it's a better form to use?

Comment: Yes. However, if mass is constant all the forms are equally good.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much! Sort of understand it now. :)

Comment: Great! Feel free to ask me to go into more detail.

Comment: @WangiPaPa Careful here.  Math allows the mass to change, but Newton's Laws do not.   Newton's laws are valid only for constant mass systems, so it must be strictly true that $\mathrm{d}m/\mathrm{d}t=0$.

Comment: @garyp so in terms of Newtonian mechanics, I would be safer with saying that F=ma, because Newton's Laws do not allow mass to change anyways? So in terms of physics F=ma will just satisfy applications of this Law? I was interested in $F=dp/dt$ because of possibilities for changes in mass, but if Newton's laws do not allow this, then perhaps F=ma would just suffice, if I am just considering Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @WangiPapa Mass can change in Newtonian mechanics. Consider a rocket blasting off: it's mass decreases as fuel is burnt. If fuel is being burnt at a constant rate the force on the rocket is constant; however, because its mass is decreasing, the accelation of the rocket will be increasing (so that F, which is a constant in this case, equals ma).

Comment: @Jeffrey Ede Check [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-mass_system) link.

Comment: @ccorbella Nice link. To clarify: the force, F, in my above comment is the net force on the rocket and the accelaration, a, is the centre of mass frame acceleration.